# WPF: Изменение текста метки внутри одного процесса несколько раз

Tags: c#, wpf

При нажатии на кнопку вижу только начальное и через 4 секунды конечное состояние метки. Как отобразить промежуточные варианты?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string labeltext;

        public string Labeltext
        {
            get
            {
                return labeltext;
            }

            set
            {
                labeltext = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Labeltext");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            setText("Sasha1");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            setText("Sasha2");            
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            setText("Sasha3");            
        }

        void setText(string text)
        {
            Labeltext = text;
        }

        private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Labeltext = "Sasha";
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    setText("Sasha1");
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    setText("Sasha2");
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    setText("Sasha3");
}
```